# Chaining a scope with 'where' results in SQL being appended (not merged)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My models look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
 has_many :created_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'challenger_id'
 has_many :challenged_games, class_name: 'Game', foreign_key: 'opponent_id'  
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :challenger, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :opponent, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

**User story**
As a user I want to see a list of users that I can challenge to play a game with. I can not challenge a user for a new game if an existing game between us exists.

**Scopes**

I have one class method as follows:

```
def self.challeangable_for(user_id)

    challengeable_users = User.joins("LEFT JOIN ( SELECT games.challenger_id, games.opponent_id FROM games where games.challenger_id = #{user_id} OR games.opponent_id = #{user_id}) as g on g.challenger_id = users.id or g.opponent_id = users.id WHERE g.challenger_id is null and g.opponent_id is null") 

end
```

This generates the list of 'challengeable users' correctly, but I can't seem to chain this query. For example, if I do `User.challengeable_users(1).where(gender: 'm')`, rails will append the WHERE clause to the end and the query will fail:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "WHERE": syntax error: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LEFT JOIN ( SELECT games.challenger_id, games.opponent_id FROM games where games.challenger_id = 1 OR games.opponent_id = 1) as g on g.challenger_id = users.id or g.opponent_id = users.id WHERE g.challenger_id is null and g.opponent_id is null WHERE "users"."gender" = 'm' ORDER BY users.created_at DESC
```

Also, it's long and ugly. Is there a better way? I tried using 'includes', but I did not find a way tp specify a **different** (non standard) foreign key to join on?

I realize I'm kind of fixated on a solution that generates a LEFT JOIN query. An alternative solution would be something that generates a EXISTS IN query, but I don't know how to write that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can rewrite it a bit:

```
challengeable_users = User.joins("LEFT JOIN ( 
  SELECT games.challenger_id, games.opponent_id FROM games where games.challenger_id = #       {user_id} OR games.opponent_id = #{user_id}
  ) as g on g.challenger_id = users.id or g.opponent_id = users.id"
).where("g.challenger_id is null").where("g.opponent_id is null")
```

And then you can further apply your gender condition.

Comment: Awesome, that works! I spent so many hours on this, but finally it starts to make sense a little bit. Thanks!